# Structure for backbone.js models and views

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, backbone.js

My application has 3 main models: companies, posts, and postdata. I'm providing an in depth analytics dashboard and am having trouble figuring out what is the best method to structure the models in mongodb for the best performance.

The postdata contains the fields: date, number of posts (for that date), average post length (for that date), and company id
The post contains the fields: date, post text, post length

In the dashboard view I want to display two graphs and two pieces of data.

graphs: one of the number of posts by date, and the other the average post length by date.
data: total number of posts for a date range, average post length for a date range

Currently in the views, I loop through the postdata collection to create a total posts number for that date range, and an average post length for that date range. I know I probably shouldn't be doing that much work in the views, but how else can I get the data I'm looking for? Should I get rid of the postdata collection and just use underscore and countBy to create the data for charts? What will give me the best performance / is the preferred method.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at Marionette, it adds a few nice features to Backbone, one of which being [collection views](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.collectionview.md) This is a nice way to separate out the view for your graphs.

If you think you'd like to grow the functionality of your dashboard to become more and more complex, then I would ditch the postdata model and do analysis on the client side, you can use libraries like [d3](http://d3js.org), [crossfilter](http://square.github.io/crossfilter/), and [rickshaw](http://code.shutterstock.com/rickshaw/). This will give you a lot of flexibility to quickly add features. The advantages of keeping the postdata model would be: simplicity on the front end and best front end performance.

Answer (score 0):

I think looping through collection shouldn't give that much impact on performance.

Although you can try something like this: additionally to BB Collection create a simple object with dates acting as keys and data object as values for calculations only. To query it you'll have to create an array of dates in requested range. It may work pretty fast if range will be relatively small but as range increases performance will get closer to just looping through the whole thing. I admit, it sounds a little crazy even to me. Some experimenting will definitely be needed.